# Calling Raycast from an Object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I usually use Physics.Raycast to raycast from an object to specific direction but i just saw a code where ray cast is happening from newly created plane object.
code is

```
ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touch);
float a;
xzPlane.Raycast(ray, out a);
```

what does it means?  xzPlane.Raycast. How raycast is calling from an object why not from physics class?

[image]

Comment: Check this: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane.Raycast.html

Comment: Thanks buddy good link

Comment: if its not Physics.Raycast its always only against the specific object. fe. the raycast of collider would only be against this specific collider. obvioulsy its a lot more performant since physics needs to check against each object in the respective layer mask (or all without layer mask)